# Show searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView when searchbar is selected

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I want to show the searchResultsTableView when my searchBar is selected.  I have tried this:

```
- (void) searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
    [self.searchDisplayController setActive:YES animated:YES];
}
```

and this:

```
- (void) searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    [self.searchDisplayController setActive:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Neither works.  In my numberOfRowsInSection method, I do have rows in the array, but the searchResultsTableView does not show until I start typing.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your searchdisplaycontroller to active in the following UISearchBarDelegate method

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar;
```

Comment: Still doesn't work.  Nothing shows in the searchbar until I start typing.